Need help understanding the 'findById' model function in Node.js and mongoose
I having an issue with findById in my project and I couldn't trace the problem.
I tried to use our 'lovely' chat, but there is nothing like real interaction.
My Model is for user
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema= mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    id: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId},
    first_name: {type: String},
    last_name: {type: String},
    birthday: {type: Date}
});

const User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;

And I am trying to create a verification function -
async function verifyUser(userID) { //verify user is a valid mongo ID
    try {
        // Check if the userID exists in the database
        console.log('Verifying user:', userID);
        const user = await User.findById(userID);
        console.log('User found:', user);
        // If user is null, it means userID does not exist in the database
        if (!user) {
            console.log('User not found');
            return false;
        }

        // If user is found, return true
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error verifying user:', error);
        throw error; // Rethrow the error to be handled by the caller
    }
}

The error is
Error verifying user: TypeError: User.findById is not a function                                     
    at Object.verifyUser (C:\Users\Adira\WebstormProjects\BackendProjectFin\verifyFunctions.js:33:33)
    at C:\Users\Adira\WebstormProjects\BackendProjectFin\routes\addcalories.js:40:49
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Error in POST / route: TypeError: User.findById is not a function
    at Object.verifyUser (C:\Users\Adira\WebstormProjects\BackendProjectFin\verifyFunctions.js:33:33) 
    at C:\Users\Adira\WebstormProjects\BackendProjectFin\routes\addcalories.js:40:49
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
POST /addcalories 500 1919.338 ms - 33


In general, I am using mongo Atlas DB,node.js, mongoose, WebStorm IDE.
Hope you guys could hand some help in here!

Can you add the code you used to import User?

You need to know how Mongoose id works. It's not like standard SQL. Mongoose uses the particular field as _id as a unique identifier. If you use module schema to findById, it checks for filed _id, not what you have set.
Reformat your schema like this:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: { type: String },
    last_name: { type: String },
    birthday: { type: Date }
});

const User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;

To get the data to correct userID to verifyUser(), you have to pass _id_ from the initial load
If you want a custom field name, use like this id: { type: String, unique: true },.

I recommend using uuid for the Users table since it's more visible to the front end.
Install:
npm install uuid

In schema:
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
_id: { type: String, default: uuidv4 },

mongoosejs Docs

Hi Abdulla, thanks for clarify how to use id in the schema.
It did helped to use the findById method!!
Again, thanks for your answer!

@אדירעמר accept if its helpls
